# Trying to create an Access 2013 query that picks dates between sept 1 of previous year and Aug 31 of current year

Tags: mysql, sql, date, ms-access-2013

The database is for workplace violence reports at a school board. I need to pick the reports that fall between eg. 09/01 of 2012 and 08/31 of 2013 or 09/01 of 2013 and 08/31 of 2014. As the database grows and adds reports, I do not want to change the date criteria annually. The months and days will stay the same but the years will have to change.

Any help is always appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: use parameters for the queries that are connected to your reports. Set these parameters i.e. with a form and two datepickers.

Comment: Why did you tag this question `mysql` when you are asking about `ms-access-2013`?

Answer (score 0):

I hope your report is based on a query. Open the query in design mode, find Year column(s) and add filter condition like this

```
= [Input year of report]
```

and

```
= [Input year of report]+1
```

If there are no Year fields, no problem. Create Year columns and make them not viewable, and add conditions.

Each time when MS Access executes the query (stand alone or within the report) it will show dialog box with prompt «Input year of report».

Also instead of `[Input year of report]` expression you may refer to a field on a form like `[Forms][Form1][FormFieldName]`. If forms is open when query is being executed, value of the field will be used. Otherwise you'll the prompt «Input [Forms][Form1][FormFieldName]»